# botocore >= 1.28.0 slower in multithread application

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, botocore

The official Boto3 docs recommends creating a new resource per thread: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html#multithreading-or-multiprocessing-with-resources

Botocore 1.28.0 merged a feature which appears to generate a list of all possible endpoints on resource creation: https://github.com/boto/botocore/pull/2785

I have a test suite which uses `motoserver` and an application that relies heavily on parallelized downloads from / uploads to s3 from a process pool. With botocore 1.28.0, the test suite takes an extra 20 minutes to run as compared to the previous version.

I've done some work with `cProfile` and I can confirm that at least half of the additional time is spent inside of `botocore`'s `load_service_model` method called during botocore client creation. Haven't tracked down the other ~50% of extra time yet but it's somewhere in botocore usage.

What can I do to speed this up again with the version bump?